# How to generate .p12 using java programmatically?

Tags: java, iphone, web-applications, struts2, apple-push-notifications

Am developing a web application in java using **Struts2** framework. From web application i have an option to send push notification. So I developed REST api's that has been used in **Android** & **iPhone**. No problem regarding android because to send push notification we just need to store the **GCM api key**. But problem is in iPhone.

In iPhone from apple we get

- developer_identity.cer
- mykey.p12

Using this we can't able to send push notification. We have to configure these certificates using **openssl command** in terminal.

```
developer_identity.cer <= download from Apple
mykey.p12 <= Your private key

openssl x509 -in developer_identity.cer -inform DER -out developer_identity.pem -outform PEM
openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -in mykey.p12 -out mykey.pem
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey mykey.pem -in developer_identity.pem -out iphone_dev.p12
```

I need to configure these certificates programmatically using java. For this I have googled and got a reference [link](https://www.mayrhofer.eu.org/create-x509-certs-in-java). But this returns null key.

Comment: does [this](http://ankursinghal86.blogspot.jp/2014/06/authentication-with-client-certificate.html) help you

Comment: Am getting security exception when using this [link](https://www.mayrhofer.eu.org/create-x509-certs-in-java)